# Jquery - zAccordion plugin responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using Jquery zAccordion plugin , I want it to be responsive . So I tried from the examples of their own website at : http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/a-responsive-example-using-media-queries/ 
Anyway , I've included zAccordion , Enquire and the script mentioned below in my wordpress website but nothing happened .
What's the problem ?
Here is the script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var example = $('#media'), defaults = {
    buildComplete: function () {
        example.css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    timeout: 5500
};
function build(x) {
    var opts, current;
    if (!$.isEmptyObject(example.data())) { /* If an zAccordion is found, rebuild it with new settings. */
        example.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        current = example.data('current');
        opts = $.extend({
            startingSlide: current
        }, defaults, x);
        example.zAccordion('destroy', {
            removeStyleAttr: true,
            removeClasses: true,
            destroyComplete: {
                afterDestroy: function() {
                    try {
                        console.log('zAccordion destroyed! Attempting to rebuild...');
                    } catch (e) {}
                },
                rebuild: opts
            }
        });
    } else { /* If no zAccordion is found, build one from scratch. */
        example.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        opts = $.extend(defaults, x);
        example.zAccordion(opts);
    }
}
/* A unique Media Query is registered for each screen size. */
enquire.register('screen and (min-width: 960px)', { /* Standard screen sizes and a default build for browsers that are unsupported. */
    match : function () {
        build({
            slideWidth: 540,
            width: 860,
            height: 200
        });
    } /* The *true* value below means this media query will fire by default. */
}, true).register('screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)', {
    match : function () {
        build({
            slideWidth: 420,
            width: 680,
            height: 200
        });
    }
}).register('screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)', {
    match : function () {
        build({
            slideWidth: 220,
            width: 380,
            height: 200
        });
    }
}).register('screen and (max-width: 479px)', {
    match : function () {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(example.data())) {
            example.zAccordion('destroy', {
                removeStyleAttr: true,
                removeClasses: true,
                destroyComplete: {
                    afterDestroy: function() {
                        try {
                            console.log('zAccordion destroyed!');
                        } catch (e) {}
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}).listen(5);
});
```

And here is the HTML :

```
<ul id="media">
<li><img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/1.jpg" width="750"  height="300" alt="Image Title"/></li>
<li><img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2.jpg" width="750" height="300" alt="Image Title"/></li>
<li><img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/3.jpg" width="750" height="300" alt="Image Title"/></li>
<li><img src="http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4.jpg" width="750" height="300" alt="Image Title"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre class="js">
$("#media").zAccordion({
   timeout: 4000,
   slideWidth: 600,
   width: 960,
  height: 270
 });
</pre>
```

Include above the code after ul tag. and remove "$" with "jQuery".

Comment: What ? this is a pre html code ! where should I include this code exactly ?